# How do you make a fixed side menu with main content scaling to the edge of the screen?

Tags: menu, fullscreen, sidebar, css

How do you create a layout where you have a fixed-width side-menu but the main content scales to the rest of screen?

Here is a sample of the markup:

```
<ul id="sideMenu">
   <li>....</li>
</ul>
<div id="mainContent">
   ... everything else ...
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Also, it would be great if we could set a min-width on mainContent as well as this working all the browsers consistently ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float the sideMenu and then set the margin of mainContent to match that.  This keeps the mainContent from wrapping around the sideMenu.

```
#sideMenu{float:left;width:200px;}
#mainContent{margin-left:200px;}
```

Comment: This is great. So elegant and works just as easily for right-floated or left-floated bars. One could only wish the css spec were clearer because this is non-obvious, but I'm glad it's much better than using tables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it may be possible by placing ur content in a table with cellspacing and cellpadding set to 0. Set the width of the td also to 100%. All u have to do is trial and error method to see.

Comment: I'd like to use to use div's if I can. I only want to use tables if I absolutely have to. I already know how to do this with tables.